# Flutter : OBD2 connectivity using bluetooth

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, connectivity, obd-ii

I want to communicate with OBD2 from my Flutter App using Bluetooth. However, I don't know how to establish a connection using Bluetooth and how to get information from OBD2.

I tried different plugins. but most of them are not working

1. [Flutter Blue Plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus)
2. [Flutter Bluetooth Serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial)

Comment: Which kind of Bluetooth does your OBD2 adapter support? Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) or Bluetooth Classic (also called Bluetooth Serial). The plugins you mentioned can only support one of both so you need to know which kind you need to support

Comment: OBD2 adapter supports Classic/Bluetooth Serial.
most popular OBD2 is **ELM327**

Comment: Then [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) should work for you. What kind of problems are you experiencing? Have you tried to communicate with the adapter via a Bluetooth terminal app to test the connection?

Comment: On Connection, I am getting a time-out error.

After modifying **connect** function natively in BluetoothConnection.java
I am able to connect using Android 10. but on Android 13 it's still not working 

**Added these lines before connecting to socket**


`Class<?> clazz = socket.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{Integer.TYPE};
        Method m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
        Object[] params = new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)};
        socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(socket.getRemoteDevice(), params);`

Comment: Looks like you created an issue on their github page as well, I think this is your best option. Maybe add some more details to it, log and error messages etc

Comment: you can get more details about error from here
https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/issues/174